# SQL copy between tables with adding constants

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I need to copy two columns from TABLE_A to TABLE_B. So far its easy:

```
insert into TABLE_B (col1,col2)
select (colA,colB)
from TABLE_A
```

but TABLE_B has few NOT NULL columns (col3 and col4) that have to be populated with constants, so I would need something like:

```
insert into TABLE_B (col1,col2,col3,col4)
select (colA,colB)
from TABLE_A, values ('abc','123')
```

But this obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

```
insert into TABLE_B (col1,col2,col3,col4)
select colA,colB, 'abc', '123'
from TABLE_A
```

This should do the trick